# Using text-align center to center the email form :

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to make an app landing Page using bootstrap framework (Bootstrap 4 alpha). While trying to align everything in center I used `text-align:center` in jumbotron id. Everything except email form aligned.

Is there any way to align email form in center as well also making sure that it remains in center irrespective of web page width.

This is the code in stylesheet.

```
.jumbotron 
{
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

This is the main code.

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">My Awesome App!</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is why YOU should download this fantastic app!</p>
    <hr class="m-y-2">
    <p>Want to know more? Join our mailing list!</p>

    <form class="form-inline" id = "emailbar">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `justify-content-center` class to `<form class="form-inline">---</form>`

Comment: don't forget to specify that you are using `bootstrap 4 alpha`. `bootstrap 3` is using inline-block, thus this is displayed correctly. `bootstrap 4` uses `display: flex` so you need to adjust how you plan to justify your items or align your content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your form has `display: flex` it spans the whole width of its parent.

Also the `text-align: center` in your `jumbotron` class won't apply to the forms element as they are flex items.

So change either of these in your `form-inline` class

- change it to `display: inline-flex`  (and the `text-align: center` will apply)
- add `justify-content: center;`  (the Flexbox property to align horizontally in row direction)

---

To target only the `emailbar`, do like this

```
#emailbar {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

or this

```
#emailbar {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add css part in `jumbotron` to get the center.

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;/*Add this*/
    flex-direction: column; /*Add this*/
    align-items: center; /*Add this*/
}
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tfeunrxp/)**

```css
.jumbotron {
    display: flex;/*Add this*/
    flex-direction: column; /*Add this*/
    align-items: center; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">My Awesome App!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is why YOU should download this fantastic app!</p>
  <hr class="m-y-2">
  <p>Want to know more? Join our mailing list!</p>
  <form class="form-inline" id="emailbar">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for extra CSS. Just use `justify-content-center` on the form...

https://www.codeply.com/go/7LjBkEtvVV

```
<form class="form-inline justify-content-center" id = "emailbar">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
</form>
```